# Subclass of AtomicReference with atomic function application

Tags: scala

*Update: Now that https://github.com/bionicspirit/scala-atomic is available, I have less of a need for this.*

Am I doing anything bad? I wrote this class to allow modifying an atomic reference with the assurance that two threads modifying it will not step on each other's toes. To illustrate:

```
val x = new AtomicRef(List.empty[String])
def compute(s: String) = { Thread.sleep(1000); s }
def updateX(s: String) = x.transform(strings => compute(s) :: strings)
```

The idea is to guarantee that if two threads call `updateX` many times, all the strings passed to `updateX` will wind up in `x`.

`run` is like `transform` but it lets you return a value to the caller other than the value you're setting into the reference.

Here is the class:

```
/**
 * A subclass of java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference[A]
 * that adds the ability to atomically modify its value relative to itself.
 */
class AtomicRef[A](init: A) extends java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference[A](init) {
  /**
   * Update the value atomically by applying a function to it.
   * Uses `compareAndSet` and will keep trying until it succeeds.
   */
 final def transform(f: A => A): A = run { a =>
    val ret = f(a)
    (ret, ret)
 }
  /**
   * Update the value atomically by applying a computation to it.
   * The computation returns a pair of values, of which the
   * `AtomicRef` is updated to the first.
   * Uses `compareAndSet` and will keep trying until it succeeds.
   * @return the second value of the computation
   */
  @annotation.tailrec final def run[B](f: A => (A, B)): B = {
    val a = get
    val (a2, b) = f(a)
    if(compareAndSet(a, a2)) b
    else {
      Thread.sleep(10)
      run(f)
    }
  }
}
```

To put it in different terms, this sort of abstracts over doing something like this (in Java; List here is a fictional immutable list):

```
AtomicReference<List<String>> ref = new AtomicReference<List<String>>(new List());
void update(String s) {
  while(true) {
    List<String> a = ref.get;
    // now do "f(a)"
    Thread.sleep(1000); // pretend it takes a long time to run the computation
    List<String> b = a.prepend(s);
    if(compareAndSet(a, b)) return b;
    else {
      Thread.sleep(10);
      // loop the while instead of tail recursion
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This cannot be really called atomic, especially the `run` function; if another thread has a reference to this `AtomicReference` it can modify the value from under your nose. What is the intent of this class exactly?

Comment: Hi @fge, apologies for not describing the intent before. I added it to the question text. Is it clear?

Comment: @fge It's true another thread can modify the value while the computation is running. But then `compareAndSet` will fail (return false) and we will try again! `compareAndSet` means don't store the result of the computation unless the value still is what the computation thought it was!

Comment: Uh, OK, I don't understand scala well enough to really comment :/

Comment: @fge thanks anyway, I added a Java snippet that illustrates the pattern, except now having functions it doesn't abstract over the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is definitely valid, I've seen something similar used in GHC's implementation of [atomicModifyIORef](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Data-IORef.html#v%3aatomicModifyIORef).

However I have some doubts if such a class is really useful. If the computations are potentially long running, the performance advantage of using `AtomicReference` instead of some standard synchronization primitive is negligible. Moreover, if there are several updating threads, it will result in repeated recomputation, wasting CPU power on it. So using plain `synchronized` on some private lock object (so that no other part of code can lock on it) seems simpler, safer and with better performance.

Comment: Okay, that's a good point. I would say that this class is designed for quick computations, but designed in a reusable way. So the decision whether to use this class would need to be made in each use site.